# Where should I put dropdown values? In database or in HTML

Tags: html, mysql, database

I have many input fields, dropdowns(select->option) in my form. Some dropdowns have many options (even more than 500 ). If I develop database, I think it will contain a lot of tables. for example, one table for student_course, one for student_country, one for student_city and so on. In my opinion, if I put them in plain HTML, then management of these might be difficult in future (in case of scalability).

If there is any effecient way to put all dropdown values in single table, please let me know. 
If no, then what is the best approach to set these values? To put them in database or in plain html.
Please elaborate the pros & cons of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to have the data in data base than in HTML as you will have to edit the code for managing data, if it is in HTML.

I would recommend using multiple tables here.

If you want to use single table, create a table with an extra column, which will indicate, which drop down(what kind of data it is) the table entry will belong to.

for example:

[image: Sample table structure included in the image]

Comment: If I use multiple tables, then there might be more than 40 tables. Is it good to have too much tables. cs I never worked on more tables just for small tasks.

Comment: Its absolutely fine to have as many tables as you want, and that is considered as the ideal way. You can use single table, if your only purpose with the data is to display in the dropdown, which I don't reccomend.

Answer (score 1):

To put them in a plain html would be a bad idea. To maintain the scalability you have to put the dropdown options either into database or in JSON file. You can make a single JSON or separate JSON like DB tables.
Thanks